# How to make a function to hide and show infobubble markers

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps

I need a checkbox to get a function to hide and show a marker or an group of markers

for some reason idk (i'm new to google maps api) the function doesnt work with infobubbles, when i tried with infowindow it works.. any help ? thanks

```
    var map;

  function init() {

    var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(-22.967956,-43.197397);
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 14,
      center: mapCenter,
      streetViewControl: true,
      mapTypeControl: true,
      mapLabels:true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    });

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-22.973878,-43.192564);
    var myLatLng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(-22.968373,-43.183176);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: myLatLng,
      title: 'marker'
     });

     var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: myLatLng1,
      title: 'marker1'
     });

     infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
      maxWidth: 246,
      maxHeight: 350


    });

    infoBubble.addTab('home', contenthome);
    infoBubble.addTab('Info', content);
    infoBubble.addTab('Fase', contentString);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', infobut); 

    function infobut(event) {

             if (!infoBubble.isOpen()) {
        infoBubble.open(map, marker);          }
        }

    infoBubble1 = new InfoBubble({
       maxWidth: 246,
      maxHeight: 350

    });

    infoBubble1.addTab('home', contenthome);
    infoBubble1.addTab('Info', content);
    infoBubble1.addTab('Fase', contentString);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', infobut1); 

    function infobut1(event) {

             if (!infoBubble1.isOpen()) {
        infoBubble1.open(map, marker1);         }
    }

    function hidemarker() {
            marker1.setVisible(false);
          }
```

and the button

```
       <input type="checkbox" onClick="hidemarker()" name="1qts" value="1 Quartos" class="botao2">
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code it is not clear where `init()` function finishes. I put close `}` just before `hidemarker()` function. Problem is that variable `marker1` is not visible and it should be made global like variable `map`.

And to close also info bubble, just call method `close()`:

```
var map;

var marker1;

function init() {
    ...
    marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: myLatLng1,
        title: 'marker1'
    });
    ...
}

function hidemarker() {
    infoBubble1.close();
    marker1.setVisible(false);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```